Classification in QSVM 2014 model: understanding the quantum circuit

This is a QSVM circuit from this paper (fig.. 1-e). I am having hard time understanding after barrier 2(in blue line).
I get that before line one, HHL is used to find the hyper-plane parameters through matrix inversion of F: $(b,{\vec{\alpha}_i}^T)^T  = {\tilde F^{ - 1}} (0,{\vec{y}_i}^T)^T$ (which we get from the least-square approximation in SVM). Thus, from input $|0\rangle |0\rangle |\vec{y}\rangle |0\rangle $ we get $|0\rangle |0\rangle |\vec{\alpha}\rangle |1\rangle +|0\rangle |0\rangle |\text{something}\rangle |0\rangle $ (am I wrong?) at line 1 ($b=0$).
$$
 |\vec{x}_i\rangle  = 1/|\vec{x}_i| \sum_{j=1}^{N}(\vec{x}_i)_j |j\rangle  \nonumber \\
|0,\vec{y}\rangle  = 1/\sqrt{N_{0,y}}(|0\rangle  + \sum_{i = 1}^M \vec{y_i} |i\rangle  \nonumber \\
|b,\vec{\alpha}\rangle  = 1/\sqrt {{N_{b,\alpha} }} (b|0\rangle  + \sum_{i = 1}^M \vec{\alpha}_i |i\rangle  \nonumber \\
|\vec{u}\rangle  = 1/\sqrt{N_{\vec{u}}} [b|0\rangle |0\rangle  + \sum_{i = 1}^M abs(\vec{x}_i)\vec{\alpha}_i|\vec{x}_i\rangle |i\rangle ]
\nonumber \\
|\vec{v_0}\rangle  = 1/\sqrt{N_{\vec{v_0}}} [|0\rangle |0\rangle  + \sum_{i = 1}^M abs(\vec{x}_0)|\vec{x}_0\rangle |i\rangle ]
$$
At line two, we get $|0\rangle |\vec{u}\rangle |1\rangle +|0\rangle |0\rangle |\text{something}\rangle |0\rangle $. After line 2 I don't get what is happening. Let me quote from the paper:

Here, the training-data state $|\vec{u}\rangle $ could be easily obtained by calling the training-data oracle (Fig. QSVM_Fig1b) on $|b,\vec{\alpha}\rangle $ and an additional training register (Fig. QSVM_Fig1a). To introduce the information of the query vector $\vec{x}_0$, a unitary inverse operation $U_{x_{0}}$ is applied to transfer $|\vec{v}_0\rangle $ to $|00\rangle $, i.e., $U_{x_{0}} |\vec{v}_0\rangle  = |00\rangle $. Then, the expansion coefficients $\langle 00| U_{x_{0}} |\vec{u}\rangle  = \langle v_0|u\rangle $ produce the classification result $y(\vec{x}_0)$. It is noted that the unitary operations are conditional operations controlled by an ancillary qubit. Hence, the final state will be $|\Psi\rangle  = |\Phi\rangle  |1\rangle _A + |00\rangle |0\rangle _A$ denoting the states of the ancillary qubit. By measuring the expectation value of the coherent term $O = \langle 00|00\rangle  * (\langle 1|0\rangle )_A$ the classification result will be revealed by $y(\vec{x}_0)$

Here, I think $|\Phi\rangle  = U_{x_{0}}|\vec{u}\rangle $ where  $U_{x_{0}}$ is implemented after line 2. What I don't get is why $|\Psi\rangle  = |\Phi\rangle  |1\rangle _A + |00\rangle |0\rangle _A$, especially $|00\rangle |0\rangle _A$ part. Where did $|00\rangle$ come from? I did not get the "By measuring the expectation value of the coherent term $O = \langle 00|00\rangle  * (\langle 1|0\rangle )_A$" part either.
Other sources: Original 2014 paper (arXiv), implementation 2015 (arXiv) paper.
